# The type of column "Change_Date" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: sql, unpivot

Having some problems with an Unpivot and not sure why. I understand the column types need to be the same and I think I have this sorted.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[zztmp1](
[Project_Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Changed_Design_Status] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Changed_Cost] [decimal](38, 4) NULL,
[Change_Date] [varchar](8) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Script

```
select  
Project_Number, 
ColumnName, Value, Change_Date
from
(
  select Project_Number, 
   Changed_Design_Status ,    
   cast(Changed_Cost as varchar(50)) Changed_Cost,
   cast(Change_Date as varchar(50)) Change_Date
  from zztmp1
) d
unpivot
(
  Value FOR 
  ColumnName in ( Changed_Design_Status-- ,Changed_Cost
  )
) unpiv;
```

When adding Change_Cost in I get the error  :

Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
The type of column "Changed_Cost" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

If I change the order and run with just change_Cost it works fine. It seems to be an issue when I have multiple columns, what am I mising.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is for SQL Server I assume?

Answer (score 0):

I find it so much easier to unpivot using `cross apply`:

```
select z.Project_Number, v.ColumnName, v.Value, z.Change_Date
from zztmp1 z outer apply
     (values ('Changed_Cost', cast(Changed_Cost as varchar(50)) ),
             ('Changed_Design_Status', cast(Changed_Design_Status as varchar(50)) )
     ) v(ColumnName, Value);
```

In your case, it probably has to do with the type of `Changed_Design_Status`.

Comment: Is that syntax correct. I get : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @user1106857 . . . It is correct if one puts in the right parentheses.